# Replace in line using sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm creating a shell script, which reads the following **list.log**

```
1.15.2.119
1.15.86.33
1.15.251.60
1.20.178.145/31
1.37.33.24
1.54.202.216
1.58.10.126/28
1.80.225.84
1.116.240.174/30
```

I would like to add a /32 IP at the end of all IPs except the ones that already exist /32 something.

Example:

```
1.14.191.227/32
1.15.2.119/32
1.15.86.33/32
1.15.251.60/32
1.20.178.145/31
1.37.33.24/32
1.54.202.216/32
1.58.10.126/28
1.80.225.84/32
1.116.240.174/30
```

My return is doubling the /32

```
cat list.log | sed 's/$/\/32/'

1.14.191.227/32
1.15.2.119/32
1.15.86.33/32
1.15.251.60/32
1.20.178.145/31/32
1.37.33.24/32
1.54.202.216/32
1.58.10.126/28/32
1.80.225.84/32
1.116.240.174/30/32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `/32` to the end of lines that do not contain `/`

```sh
sed  '\,/,!s,$,/32,' list.log > newlist.log
```

*Details*:

- `\,/,!` - find lines not containing `/`
- `s,$,/32,` - and replace end of string position with `/32` there.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/o0cHvt):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='1.15.2.119
1.15.86.33
1.15.251.60
1.20.178.145/31
1.37.33.24
1.54.202.216
1.58.10.126/28
1.80.225.84
1.116.240.174/30'

sed  '\,/,!s,$,/32,' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
1.15.2.119/32
1.15.86.33/32
1.15.251.60/32
1.20.178.145/31
1.37.33.24/32
1.54.202.216/32
1.58.10.126/28
1.80.225.84/32
1.116.240.174/30
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily done in `awk`, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '!/\/32$/{$0=$0"/32"} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, checking condition if line doesn't ending with `/32` then add `/32` to current line and mentioning `1` will print edited/non-edited current line.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's|\.[0-9]\+$|&/32|' list.log
1.15.2.119/32
1.15.86.33/32
1.15.251.60/32
1.20.178.145/31
1.37.33.24/32
1.54.202.216/32
1.58.10.126/28
1.80.225.84/32
1.116.240.174/30
```